# Python xlsxwriter does not create workbook on exit code -1

Tags: python, excel

I am writing a python code to implement some logic and record it in excel sheet. xlsxwriter works fine when program terminates properly but if it is terminated through some logical error in the code or through any exceptions or interrupts the excel workbook is not created.

I tried even xlwt and the behaviour is same.
Here's my code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import time
try:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write('A1', 'write something')
    time.sleep(5)
    # some logic implementation
    worksheet.write("B1","write something")
finally:
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version `0.7.3` xlsxwriter added support for Python's `with` context manager, so it is no longer necessary to have an explicit `workbook.close()` statement.

You could try wrapping your code as follows:

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx') as workbook:
    try:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write('A1', 'write something A1')
        print 1/0           # Generate an exception
        worksheet.write('A2', 'write something A2')
    except:
        worksheet.write('A3', 'write something A3')
```

The resulting output xlsx file should contain `A1` and `A3`. Having just a `finally` clause will not catch the exception.

You can determine which version you are running by doing the following:

```
import xlsxwriter
print xlsxwriter.__version__
```